# Matrix multiplication in py-spark using RDD

Tags: pyspark, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices

```
# 3x3 matrix
    X = [[10,7,3],[3 ,2,6],[5 ,8,7]]
# 3x4 matrix
    Y = [[3,7,11,2],[2,7,4,10],[8,7,6,11]]
```

I want to multiply these two in spark using RDD. Can some one help me on this. This multiplication should not use any inbuilt function.

I was able to multiply the 2 using for loop in python as follows

```
    for i in range(len(X)):
    # iterate through columns of Y
        for j in range(len(Y[0])):
    # iterate through rows of Y
            for k in range(len(Y)):
                Output[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j] 
    #output is a 3*4 empty matrix
```

I am new to spark and using pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so hard, you just have to write your matrix using a different notation.

```
 X = [[10,7,3],[3 ,2,6],[5 ,8,7]]
```

Can be written as

```
  X = (0,0,10),(0,1,7),(0,2,3)...
```

rdd_x = sc.parallelize((0,0,10),(0,1,7),(0,2,3)...)
rdd_y = sc.parallelize((0,0,3),(0,1,7),(0,2,11)...)

Now you can make the multiplication both using join or cartesian.
E.g.,

```
    rdd_x.cartesian(rdd_y)\
.filter(lambda x: x [0][0] == x[1][1] and x[0][1] == x[1][0])\
.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][2] * x[1][2])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()
```

Comment: In 2*2 matrix , above code only prints (0,0) and (1,1) values only. How to get the values for (0,1) and (1,0)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but you should initialize Output, and only once,

```
Output=[[0]*4]*3
```

You're not using RDDs though, your teacher won't be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andrea's answer, I came up with this solution:

```
rdd_x.cartesian(rdd_y)\
.filter(lambda x: (x[0][1] == x[1][0]))\
.map(lambda x: ((x[0][0],x[1][1]),x[0][2] * x[1][2])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()
```